# QThread start() return value

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class which inherits QThread. QThread's start() function does not return any value. When I call start() function of my class how can I know if the thread is successfully started or not?

Comment: How about [`QThread::isRunning()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isRunning)?

Comment: You should connect to and listen for the [`started`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#started) signal.

Comment: Should I write a separate slot to know if the thread is started?

Comment: I want to terminate my program if the thread is not started.

Comment: And when the thread is started, the process () method is called, which will create the Report Builder, `connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()))`  Which will work in a new thread

Answer (score 0):

Hi i dont know what is your code but here an example how to manage thread(one of them cause theres alot thread method an all depend of you , what you want and wich kind of approach you use.In the example i gave you look at ScanThread.cpp where you see the qDebug()'s this is how for me i know that something is going on like (qDebug() << "Trying to open the blacklist " ;) here i know the thread is trying to open the blacklist and if the thread wasnt running the qDebug() wouldnt show message on the application output.To know if a thread is running you have also isRunning() method that can be use a bit like start() for me in the program i gave you as example i log a file to tell my program that the thread as ended and it can be closed otherwise its impossible to close it (so the thread read the log file and the mainwindow read it if he read #1313 thats mean he can close.For you it would be if the logs file = "" then close.To close you can use QCloseEvent as i did here.

**ScanThread.h**

```
#ifndef SCANTHREAD_H
#define SCANTHREAD_H
#include <QtCore>

class ScanThread :public QThread
{
public:
    ScanThread();
    void run() ;
};

#endif // SCANTHREAD_H
```

**ScanThread.cpp**

```
#include "scanthread.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>

QString Root ;
QString Path ;
QString Match ;
QString BlackList = ":/BlackList.txt" ;

ScanThread::ScanThread()
{

}

void ScanThread::run()
{

    /* Getting storage name C:/ D:/ E:/ etc..*/
    QStorageInfo storage_name = QStorageInfo::root() ;
    Root = storage_name.rootPath() ;

    QDirIterator Load_Path(Root, QDirIterator::Subdirectories) ;

    /* scannning all possible path of the principal dir */
    do
    {

        QFile Write_Path("path.temp") ;

        if(Write_Path.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Append))
        {
            QTextStream out(&Write_Path) ;

            Path = QString (Load_Path.next()) ;

            out << Path << endl ;

            qDebug() << "im looking for environment " << Path ;
        }
        Write_Path.flush() ;
        Write_Path.close() ;

    }while(Load_Path.hasNext()) ;

    /* setuping the scan */
    qDebug() << "Trying to setup the scan " ;

    QFile Read_Path("path.temp") ;
    QFile Read_Blacklist(BlackList) ;

    if(Read_Path.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&Read_Path) ;

        /* read path.temp(contain all dir path */
        qDebug() << "Trying to read path.temp" ;
        while(!Read_Path.atEnd())
        {
Scan:
            Path = in.readLine() ;
            if(Path == "")
            {
                goto EndScan ;
            }
            else
            {
                /* look for path one by one */
                QFile Logs_CurrentPath("CurrentP.temp") ;

                if(Logs_CurrentPath.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
                {
                    QTextStream out(&Logs_CurrentPath) ;

                    out << Path ;
                }
                Logs_CurrentPath.flush() ;
                Logs_CurrentPath.close() ;
            }

            /* open blacklist from ressource */
            qDebug() << "Trying to open the blacklist " ;


            if(Read_Blacklist.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
            {
                /* compare path file and words in blacklist */
                QTextStream in(&Read_Blacklist) ;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 62218 ; i ++)
                {
                    Match = in.readLine() ;

                    QFile Logs_ListState("ListState.temp") ;

                    if(Logs_ListState.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
                    {
                        QTextStream out(&Logs_ListState) ;
                        out << i ;
                    }
                    Logs_ListState.flush() ;
                    Logs_ListState.close() ;

                    qDebug() << "Scanning for potential threat" ;
                    qDebug() << Match ;
                    qDebug() << Path ;

                    if(Path.contains(Match) == true)
                    {
                        /* theres a threat do something */

                    }

                }
            }
            Read_Blacklist.flush() ;
            Read_Blacklist.close() ;
            goto Scan ;
        }

        /* end the scan once Read_Path is at end */
        if(Read_Path.atEnd())
        {
EndScan:
            qDebug() << "Scan Complete ";


            Read_Path.flush() ;
            Read_Path.close() ;

            QFile WriteEnd("CurrentP.temp") ;

            if(WriteEnd.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
            {
                QTextStream out(&WriteEnd) ;

                out << "#1313" << endl ; //#1313 dev code to manually signal that the scans as been completed
            }
            WriteEnd.flush() ;
            WriteEnd.close() ;
            /* terminate thread */
            ScanThread::terminate() ;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void Queud() ;

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e) ;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *timer ;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "scanthread.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QStorageInfo>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QCloseEvent>

using namespace std ;

QString Read_CurrentPath ;
float LoadBar = 0 ;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    /* launch timer to update ui */
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Queud()));
    timer->start(1000);

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::Queud()
{

        /* looking for list state wich word is beign tested */
        QFile ReadLog_Count("ListState.temp") ;

        if(ReadLog_Count.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            QTextStream in(&ReadLog_Count) ;

            in >> LoadBar ;

            //qDebug() << LoadBar ;
        }
        ReadLog_Count.flush() ;
        ReadLog_Count.close() ;

        /* looking wich current path is beign tested */
        QFile ReadLog_CurrentPath("CurrentP.temp") ;

        if(ReadLog_CurrentPath.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            QTextStream in(&ReadLog_CurrentPath) ;

            Read_CurrentPath = in .readLine();

            //qDebug() << read_temp ;
        }
        ReadLog_CurrentPath.flush() ;
        ReadLog_CurrentPath.close() ;

        LoadBar = (LoadBar / 62218) * 100 ;

        if(Read_CurrentPath == "")
        {
          /* theres an error the path caint be empty */
        }
        else
        {
            /* receive the signal #1313 mean boss i finish my work */ 
            if(Read_CurrentPath == "#1313") //#1313 dev code to manually signal that the scans as been completed
            {
                LoadBar = 0 ;
                ui->Path_Status->setText("Scan Complete") ;
                ui->LoadBar->setValue(0) ;

                timer->stop() ;
            }
            else
            {
                ui->Path_Status->setText(Read_CurrentPath) ;
            }
        }

        /* update load bar as it needed */
        if(LoadBar == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ui->LoadBar->setValue(LoadBar);
        }

}

/* close program handling */
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    /* can close normally */
    if(Read_CurrentPath == "#1313")
    {
        timer->stop() ;
        e->accept() ;
    }
    /* dont close the program untill scan complete its not a --->bloatware<--- */
    else
    {
        QMessageBox MSG ;
        MSG.setText("You are about to close ,the scan is incomplete.\n Leaving while the scan still running can occur errors \n please wait..");
        MSG.exec() ;


        e->ignore() ;
    }

}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "scanthread.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    /* start that thread */ 
    ScanThread sThread ;
    sThread.start() ;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You inherit your class from [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html), so you can call function `start();` easily.

Also you can call functions `isRunning();` or `quit();`

Check this sample:

```
void SecondClass::startThread()
{
    if(!isRunning()) 
    {
        start();

        // use signal to find out thread is running or not
        connect(this, &QThread::started, this, &SecondClass::yourSlotName);

        //if thread is running qDebug
        if(isRunning())
            qDebug()<<"Thread Started."
    }
}
```